# Centering link below images

Tags: html, css

How to center link below my images, I tried everything. When I use `clear:both` this helped me, but then my images are in one column and I do not want that. So basically I want bellow every picture centered link/text. I know that this HTML/CSS does not contains links that I wanted to put below images, I deleted everything that can be confusing.

Thanks.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 0%;
  clear: both;
}
.products img {
  width: 31%;
  height: 31%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 2% 3% 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Products</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/products.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/tunel.jpg" alt="Product name">
      </a>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the text?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

Don't float the images, float the links.

Make the images `display:block` and add `text-align:center` to the links.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #F0FFF0;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 0%;
  clear: both;
}
.products a {
  width: 31%;
  height: 31%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2% 3% 0%;
  text-align: center
}
.products a img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Products</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/products.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="products">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" alt="Product name">Link Text
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" alt="Product name">Link Text
      </a>

      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" alt="Product name">Link Text
      </a>


    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks,but now when i hover over image or over white space around text/link the same text/link becoming active and acting like it is part of image?I wanted to text/link is separate from image. Sorry if i haven't been clear about this. @Paulie_D

Comment: There's no link text in your question...where is it supposed to be and why wouldn't it be inside the link?